# Sort by similar words?

Tags: mysql

So, I have a single column that would have different string values, is it possible to sort it based on similarities in the string?

e.g. table.name would be '3d audio' , but then we would have table.name to be '3d audio and entertainment' and other possible scenarios, however '3d audio is just example' - any string is possible, so I cant filter by certain strings.

I know I've asked this, however I asked it as a secondary question to another one and it felt like it was overlooked

```
select pt.id, pt.name ,pt2.name from product_taxonomy pt
left join product_taxonomy pt2 on pt2.name = pt.name
where pt.name like pt2.name
```

This does not seem to be working at all, as I want to compare pt.name with the next instance of pt2.name, so lets say I have id = 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5
so I want to compare pt.name with id=1 to pt.name with id=2 and so on

Comment: Can you give a small example of input and desired output?

Comment: Feels like a dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259404/finding-similar-complimentary-values